# How can I resolve a ClassNotFoundEception of Qt app on an Android device?

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface, classnotfoundexception

I'm using Qt for Android and JNI to access Android APIs. This works fine, if I run the app in simulators with a virtual Android device but not on a physical Android device. This is confusing.

I develop with Qt Creator 4.11.0 based on Qt 5.14.0 (Clang 10.0 (Apple), 64 bit). Here is the stack trace of the exception:

```
W System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.launcher.worker.AppWorker" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]
W System.err:   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
W System.err:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
W System.err:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative$7.run(QtNative.java:387)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:61)
W System.err:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Has someone any idea? I assume it's not a bug in the source code, but somewhere else, maybe in the kit settings. I have used a Qt template for my project.

Comment: Maybe an obfuscation (minification) issue? That is, maybe you have different obfuscation settings for different build types, and you are trying to run a different build type on the physical device than what you wre on the emulator(?).

Comment: I have no idea, where I can find this settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I have created a new app from the template of Qt Creator and compared it with the [example project](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-qtandroidextras.html) for Qt Android:

I conclude, that I have to modify the .pro file. First of all I had to add the following line:

```
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android-sources
```

Then I had to replace `DISTFILES`, that is automatically added by Qt Creator, if I create a Java class:

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    main.qml \
    android-sources/src/com/hello/android/Backend.java \
    android-sources/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Finally I had to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml`, that I have copied from the exmaple project, in the text editor mode:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" android:name="com.hello.android.Backend" android:label="Hello Android" android:screenOrientation="unspecified">
```

The last step was not necessary in the project of my initial question.